# Why are the variables received correctly, in printf, in the first iteration of the for loop, but not the remaining?

Tags: c

```
for (n = 1; n <= num1, n++)
{
    num2 = num1 - n;
    printf("%*s%*c\n", num2, "", n, '#');   
}
```

I'm trying to get a half-pyramid of hashtags, with the bottom-left corner left-aligned, and the height x width determined by a single input(num1). Like this:

```
num1 = 4

Output:
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Instead, I'm getting this (with an input of 4):

```
   #
   #
   #
   #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%*c` is a specifier for width or precision of the field.  You're not printing `n` characters, you're just printing one character padded `n` spaces.

If you want to print a character multiple times, use a `for` loop.

Comment: If my answer works for you, then please accept it by flagging it with a green check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here is a favorite. It takes the width as the first argument to the program (default 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int width = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : 5;
    if (width < 0) width = -width;

    char *hash = "################################################";
    size_t max = strlen (hash);
    char *p = hash + max;
    int i = width > max ? max : width;

    while (i--)
        printf ("%*s\n", width, p -width + i);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/padstr_hash
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####

$ ./bin/padstr_hash 6
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```